# Save file with different name using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire, nsfilemanager

I am using Alamofire to download files from the server. But i want to name it differently just like how we download the file from web and can name it as we want, same How is it possible in swift

I am using the following code:-

```
Alamofire.download(fileUrl, to: destination)
        .downloadProgress { progress in
            print("Download Progress:---------- \   
        (progress.fractionCompleted)")


        }
        .responseData { response in

            print(response.request)
            print(response.response)
            print(response.temporaryURL)
            print(response.destinationURL)
            print(response.error)

    }
```

Prefering not to use alamofire to rename or overrite files. Is there any other method

Comment: Do you want to save downloaded data with your custom name to app's document directory ?

Comment: yes, I want to save files with different names in document directory

Comment: Please look into my answer. Let me know if you faced any issue in this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the hands on function to save your `Data` into **DocumentDirectory** with the name you given. This method have one `call back` which will call after performing saving action, it will return the path where the image saved in directory. This function written in `Swift 3`.

```
func saveImageInDocDirectory(data: Data?, fileName: String?, successblock: @escaping (_ path: String?) -> Void) { // To add the image to cache for given identifier.

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( .documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let path = paths.appending("/\(fileName!)")
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("Error creating images folder in Cache dir: \(error)")
        }
    }

    if (filemgr.fileExists(atPath: path)) {
        try! filemgr.removeItem(atPath: path)
    } else {
        do {
            try data?.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: path, isDirectory: false))
            successblock(path)
        } catch {
            successblock(nil)
            print("Error while caching the data in cache folder.")
        }
    }

}
```

you can call this method like,

```
Alamofire.download(fileUrl, to: destination)
    .downloadProgress { progress in
        print("Download Progress:---------- \   
    (progress.fractionCompleted)")


    }
    .responseData { response in

        print(response.request)
        print(response.response)
        print(response.temporaryURL)
        print(response.destinationURL)
        print(response.error)
       if let data = response.result.value {
         self.saveImageInDocDirectory(data: data, fileName: "YourFile",  successblock: { (path) in

                print(path)

            }
       }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But i am using Alamofire to download the content as per requirement.

Comment: Im also using alamofire to download data. Please see my updated answer.